# Stratum: How many shares should I submit per job?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, client, development, stratum

I'm implementing a bitcoin CPU miner **just for fun** in python. I've been reading a lot about bitcoin and the protocol pools use for communication and coordinating workers but there is a key concept I haven't explicitly found.

#### The problem (Stratum v1)

Jobs keep coming to the worker(which I store in a FIFO), and provided `clean_jobs` is set to `false`, when should I get to the next job? With `nonce`, `extranonce`, and version and time rolling seems like I would never need to change job(even with the fastest of ASICs). Or is it that once I found a share for a given job I must submit that only one share and proceed to the next job?

**Once a share is found for a given job, should I keep mining it? Until when? Or should I submit that only one share for that job and proceed to the next job?**

I'm guessing it is the latter, as the server can adjust the difficulty to prevent me from finding shares too fast(or too slow)

I would appreciate it if you added a source if possible(so I can learn more and see what else I've missed).